# Disable scheduling another build if previous one is running in Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have a build that polls SVN and checks for changes every hour. if it finds changes it starts building.

Right now if it sees changes and a previous build (from the same job) is running, it will queue the build and start it when the previous build finishes.

Is there an option to disable the queuing of multiple builds ?

Comment: Good idea for a plugin. I'm gonna do it. It should be ready by tommorow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround: let one job (*Trigger*) do the polling and then call the main job (*MainJob*) that will do the updating and building. You can even use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to pass the SVN revisions and URIs.  You then check off *Block build when downstream project is building* in *Trigger*.

To propagate change-sets from *Trigger* to *MainJob* use [BlameSubversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion).

(BTW, here's a neat trick: *Trigger* does not have to check out the whole SVN tree, you can check it out by hand with `--set-depth empty` in the working copy of *Trigger*).

Comment: Nice workaround. I just find it hard to accept that there isn't an option or plugin that will let me disable queuing builds. it sounds like something very basic.

Comment: I agree. You already have "block when upstream/downstream job building", why not to have "block when this job is building"? Maybe there is an easy way out that I'm missing.